# Preferred location for file shared between application and it's widget on mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, widget, appstore-sandbox

I have application to which i'm trying to add widget too. 
I wonder where should i put files which i want to use between application and the widget (sql lite database for core data).

Currently app data is inside:
~/Library/Application Support/my.app/

And widget data is inside:
~/Library/Application Support/my.app.widget/

Sandboxing is on on both (as it's required). 
I wold like the sql file to be accessible from both app and the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ["The Application Group Container Directory" section of Apple's App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW21):

> an application can use the `com.apple.security.application-groups`
>   entitlement to request access to a shared container that is common to
>   multiple applications produced by the same development team. This
>   container is intended for content that is not user-facing, such as
>   shared caches or databases.

What this means is that you can obtain the path to your application group containers by using the ["`containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier`" method of NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:) to get the path to your application & widget's shared data folder.